# Simplify the restructuring of json data

Tags: python, python-2.x, json

I am trying to ad nested to some flat data, which is nested.

Basically this code works the following way:

1. "taglevel":1 tags should be key of the array
2. "taglevel":2 or higher tags should be nested within an array and not be duplicated in its' array
3. If no "taglevel":1 exists add, it to a generic "NoLevel_1" array

The code is still clunky and I feel there is a much cleaner way to achieve this.

```
import json
generic = []
result = []

for i in json_data:
    if any(d['taglevel'] == 1 for d in i['tag']):
        tag_data = {}
        tag_child = []
        for tag in i['tag']:
            if tag['taglevel'] == 1:
                tag_data['name'] = tag['name']
                tag_data['taglevel'] = 1
            else:
                tag_child.append(tag)
        filtered = {tuple((k, d[k]) for k in sorted(d) if k in ['name']): d for d in tag_child}
        tag_data['tag_child'] = list(filtered.values())
        if any(d['name'] == tag_data['name']  for d in result):
            for t in result:
                if t['name'] == tag_data['name']:
                    t['tag_child'] = t['tag_child'] + tag_child
                filtered = {tuple((k, d[k]) for k in sorted(d) if k in ['name']): d for d in t['tag_child']}
            t['tag_child'] = list(filtered.values())
        else:
            result.append(tag_data)
    else:
        for tag in i['tag']:
            generic.append(tag)
tag_data = {}
tag_data['name'] = 'NoLevel1'
tag_data['taglevel'] = 1
tag_data['tag_child'] = generic
result.append(tag_data)
print json.dumps(result, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

## The data:

```
json_data = [{
        "title": "Random",
        "tag": [
            {
                "name": "Fruit",
                "taglevel": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Apple",
                "taglevel": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Other",
        "tag": [
            {
                "name": "Fruit",
                "taglevel": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Apple",
                "taglevel": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Words",
        "tag": [
            {
                "name": "Food",
                "taglevel": 2
            }
        ]
    },
        {
        "title": "That",
        "tag": [
            {
                "name": "Food",
                "taglevel": 2
            },
            {
                "name": "Apple",
                "taglevel": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

## Desired result

```
[
    {
        "name": "Fruit", 
        "tag_child": [
            {
                "name": "Apple", 
                "taglevel": 2
            }
        ], 
        "taglevel": 1
    }, 
    {
        "name": "NoLevel_1", 
        "tag_child": [
            {
                "name": "Food", 
                "taglevel": 2
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Apple", 
                "taglevel": 2
            }
        ], 
        "taglevel": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you need to keep all that redundant information in your output or is it flexible and you can change it?

Comment: Which parts are considered redundant? The desired result is basically how I want it. As a bonus, would be great if I could sort within the tag_child also (eg alphabetically, or if I had created, by date)

Comment: I feel like keeping `"taglevel": 1` for the first level of dictionnaries and `"taglevel": 2` for the second level, for instance, is highly redundant. Also, you handle levels 1 and 2 but could there be more of them?

Comment: No, taglevel 1 will need to be the first level always. If anything, it my be good to have an easy ability to exclude items below taglevel 3 for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you may or may not considered this a simplification but this is how I would approach it.

You could use a `set` to handle the duplication part.

You can't store a `dict` in a set though so we need to create a `tuple` from the values. (It looks like you're doing something similar with `filtered`)

We then reformat `result` to get the desired final structure.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(set)

for item in json_data:
    parent   = {'name': 'NoLevel_1'}
    children = []
    for tag in item['tag']:
        if tag['taglevel'] == 1:
            parent = tag
        else:
            children.append((tag['taglevel'], tag['name']))
    result[parent['name']].update(children)

result = [ 
    {
        'name': parent, 
        'tag_child': [
            {'name': name, 'taglevel': taglevel} for taglevel, name in tags
        ],
        'taglevel': 1, 
    } for parent, tags in result.items()
]
```

You could use `next()` and a list comprehension for the `parent` and `child` creation however it iterates the tags twice and may not be as *"readable"*

```
parent   = next((tag for tag in item['tag'] if tag['taglevel'] == 1), {'name': 'NoLevel_1'})
children = [(tag['taglevel'], tag['name']) for tag in item['tag'] if tag['taglevel'] != 1]
```

Comment: You could use a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset), which can be dictionary keys.

Comment: Wow- thanks. A much more efficient and clean way to do it.